# How to tile images such that all space on an A4 page is used up?

Tags: export, printing

how to tile images in a pdf A4 page such that most of the space is used up?

### here is my attempt:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/miSFZ.png"];
flaggy[x___] := ImageResize[img, 300];
SystemOpen @ Export["~/Desktop/flagGrid.pdf", Grid[Array[flaggy, {9, 3}] ] , ItemSize -> All]
```

output after printing with default settings:
[image]

## how do I make the flags grow such that they use up more of the A4 page?

Comment: I use `pdfcrop` command. Not Mathematica for this. Simply generate the pdf image as is, then later in your makefile you use or the script, just call crop command. There might be a way to do it from inside Mathematica, but I never bother with it, since I use crop for everything. See [how-can-i-easily-crop-a-pdf-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538574/how-can-i-easily-crop-a-pdf-page) crop removes all the white space around. You can tell it how much margin you want and so on. see help on the command.

Comment: thanks, I'll try to do it using your way

Comment: btw, `pdfcrop` comes preinstaleld in TeXlive.  So you if you have Latex on your PC (which everyone should :), you already have it there.  `which pdfcrop` gives for me 
`/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux/pdfcrop`  On windows _it should be_ under MikTex  but you can google this.

Comment: Why not simply increasing the image size?

Comment: @DanielHuber increase the image size to what?

Comment: Try e.g.: `flaggy[x___] := ImageResize[img, 1000];`